# Strange issue with intent startActivity causing my scanner to not work properly

Tags: java, android, android-activity, barcode-scanner

So, after I finish my scanner activity with

```
      btn_take_photo.setOnClickListener(new FloatingActionButton.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String carde = cardnumberbox.getText().toString().trim();
            if (carde.matches("")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.Skan_Udfyld_Kort_Nummer), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                cardnumberbox.requestFocus();
                return;
            }
            Intent i = new Intent(ScanActivity.this, CameraActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID", carde);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
```

to go to my cam activity so I can take some pictures and go back with

```
    public void btn_aprove2(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(CameraActivity.this, ScanActivity.class);
    String counts = count.getText().toString().trim();
    i.putExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_IDs", counts);
    String carde = cardnumberbox2.getText().toString().trim();
    i.putExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID", carde);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
```

to the scanneractivity again. My scanner does not work properly
but if I then press the back button it does go back to the scanneractivity again instead of my menu so it seems like the scanneractivity is running twice and only 1 of them are functional but is here where it confuses me

cause if do not press the `btn_aprove2` button and just use the back button instead
i gets the exact same issue but here my scanneractivity is not runned twice as when i press the back button it just takes me back to the menu

[a video of the issue](https://youtu.be/a0GHtcoWr1E)

by removing my screen orientation from the manifest (so i can rotate it)
my scanner do now work but only if i first rotate to landscape and rotate it back to potrait

and i see in the log is that it is only calling the oncreate when rotating and only on resume and pause on the button's(startactivity/finnish)

I am totally lost on how to get this to work.

[on github](https://github.com/DirtyNightmare/Newland-n5000-app) with api demo and documentation in the wiki and with thoose classes that are being used

Comment: Are you using any library for scanning through your camera.?

Comment: i do not scan througth the cam as this is a newland n5000 so there is a inbuild 2d barcode reader for that i am using their api zltd_decoder which you can get by request but i have it uploaded here https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByzowKEghTyWcFVXSlpJTzlpRjA

Comment: i wonder if there might be a way to make it act the same way when i opening it up from the menu?

as i thougth `i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` and `finish();` should do

Comment: I have two questions: 1. as long as you are going to CamerActivity to fetch a result, why don't you launch it with `startActivityForResult()`. 2. Why are you applying `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`?

Comment: 1. i only using the cardnumber to name the picture after the cards and getting the cardnumber and how many pictures it had taken back to the scann activity with the putextra so i can update its location

2. that was for testing to see if it would give me a fresh activity to make the scanner work again the same way i do when i starting up the app

Comment: @KewinBjörkNielsen, can you post a simple demonstrative project with that behaviour at github?

Comment: i don't think you would be able to replicate that error as you need that phone to being able to use the app/api but i have uploaded it here
https://github.com/DirtyNightmare/Newland-n5000-app
with the documentation for the api with a demo app for it 

and uploaded my own project with the scan,cam,menu,main activity

Comment: the github code has a lot of empty `catch` clauses

Comment: thats something that will be used in the final relase for logging but that shouldn't causing this issue

Comment: i mean, the absence of exception handling might be hiding the cause of a possible problem and we're here wasting our time when a stack trace could point to the answer you need

Comment: here are the android open source code guidelines, which are good guidelines in a general way. See what they say about exceptions https://source.android.com/source/code-style.html

Comment: Could you try by removing i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); and finish()

Comment: @nandsito don't you think i had alredy tryed a stack trace? but it do not 
show this error

Comment: @Rasi i had updatet my answer and
i did alot more test and managed to figure out when exactly i get this issue and this conffuses me more

Comment: @KewinBjörkNielsen Please post your answer

Comment: Why does CameraActivity start a ScanActivity instead of just finishing?

Comment: @ReubenScratton it was for testing diffrent startactivies

Answer (score 4):

If you just jump to the Camera activity to get some data, I'd recommend you to start the activity for a result (startActivityForResult) without finishing the Scanner activity at all. This would give you a proper working back stack (using back button to go back from Camera to Scanner).

Besides that why are you using         `i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`? You are starting a new activity and finishing the old one. I don't see why this flag is really needed. What is your `android:launchMode` in your manifest and are you sure you know what `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` is doing and it is what you want?

Anyways from what you told us it looks like your example really should utilize `startActivityForResult()` without calling `finish()`:

1. Press menu button on some activity
2. Start camera and do something
3. Press some button to start Scanner
4. Scan something and finish the scanner with the result (or cancel the scanner by clicking back)
5. Retrieve the result of the scanner in the camera and do something with it or continue with the previous workflow when scanner was cancelled
6. Once you are finished with your workflow, finish the camera so you end up in your activity where you started the camera

Comment: i haven't setted any launchmode up in my manifest

using `startActivityForResult(i, 1)` without flag's and finish didn't solved the issue

Comment: I think I don't quiet understand your flow. So from the menu, you open the camera. From the camera you go to the scanner. From the scanner you go back to the camera and from the camera again to the scanner?

Comment: actualy is the other way around menu>scanner>camera>scanner>finish

Comment: So you would have to start the camera activity for result without finishing the scanner. e.g. Intent intent = new Intent(this, Camera.class); intent.putExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID", carde);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_PICTURES);

Don't call finish on the scanner and don't set the flag. Instead implement onActivityResult in your scanner activity

Comment: what is `REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_PICTURES` as it cannot resolve symbol

Comment: if you start activities for results, you have to provide a integer which is your result code. Usually you define a custom constant for this integer and then in onActivityResult, you check if the result code matches the one you started the activity with. This is because a activity can start multiple activities and so you can identify which result you are handling.

Comment: thats still the same

Comment: What happen if you are just in your scanner and you have a config change like orientation change? Is your activity properly destroyed and recreated and does is still work?

Comment: i removed my screen orientation from the manifest but now if i just rotate my scanner works

Comment: Is your Activity destroyed during config change? You can add "Log.d" statements to your lifecycle methods (onCreate, onDestroy, etc) to monitor the lifecycle of your scanner when you rotate the screen vs when you open your camera activity. For which reason did you remove rotation from your manifest?

Comment: And can you reupload the video showing the issue? What exactly does not work?

Comment: i have reuploaded it 
and i the only things i have for the lifecycle is the oncreate and i only see that it is calling the oncreate every time i rotate but in the log it is only calling the on resume and pause when i start the cam and the scan again

and that was for testing the rotation

Comment: According to the Activity Lifecycle (https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRxIQ.png) your activity is not recreated created again when it is stopped. Maybe your scanner is similar to the camera and should be correctly paused and resumed. Ideally you only do the setup of all necessary dependencies in onCreate and use onPause and onResume() to stop and restart the scanner. You can always be sure onResume() is called, even if your acivity is created for the first time

Comment: Might the issue be that in onCreate, you set the focust to cardnumberbox via "cardnumberbox.requestFocus();" but when you return from the camera activity, the EditText has no longer focus and your scanner input goes into nothing (scanners with which I worked in the past were used like keyboards and they would just simulate key strokes)?

Comment: this one works abit diffrent as it paste it in to the edittexts 

and on mine i maded it work out with handler and hashmap so it actualy do not matter where it has the focus at 
as you can see here as it paste it directly into the right edittext's
https://github.com/DirtyNightmare/Newland-n5000-app/blob/master/App/scan/ScanActivity.java

Comment: this one works abit diffrent as it paste it in to the edittexts 

and on mine i maded it work out with handler and hashmap so it actualy do not matter where it has the focus at  as it paste it directly into the right edittext
as you can see here on onDecoderResultChanage and private Handler mHandler 
https://github.com/DirtyNightmare/Newland-n5000-app/blob/master/App/scan/ScanActivity.java

Comment: Can you try the following: create a completely new activity for your scanner which does nothing more than just displaying the scan result on a label. Do just the bare minimum setup to get your scanning working. Then add a button or fab to start another activity for result. Then test what happens when you come back to the scanner. does it still work or does it break also?